# How to evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^{1000}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to get a limit of $b_n=\frac{n!}{n^{1000}}$. I'm using a ratio lemma, so

$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{1000}}\times\frac{n^{1000}}{n!}=(n+1)(\frac{n}{n+1})^{1000}=(n+1)(\frac{1}{1+1/n})^{1000}\rightarrow\infty$.

Now WolframAlpha give me that this tends to 0. What am I missing?

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%21%2Fn%5E1000+limit

Comment: you are correct. I think wolfram alpha found that first few terms are tend to be zero

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1926106/limit-of-n-nk-as-n-goes-to-infinity

Comment: Only for large n you begin to see it grow.

Comment: For $n>2000$, you've can pair up factors in the numerator (first-to-last, move inward) to easily get more than $1000$ factors $\geq n$, making it (significantly) larger than the denominator, so the limit must be $\infty$.

Comment: Interestingly, WolframAlpha fails even though its Backend, Mathematica, gives the right result 

Comment: Thanks all. I thought I cannot even do the ratio lemma properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this much simply by writing $n! $ as $$n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-999)\cdot(n-1000)! =p(n) \cdot(n-1000)!$$ where $p(n) $ is a monic polynomial of degree $1000$ so that $p(n) / n^{1000}\to 1$. And clearly $(n-1000)!\to\infty $ and hence the desired limit is $\infty $.

Comment: Paramand.Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

WolframAlpha gave you $ \lim_{n \to \infty}b_n$ !

You have calculated $ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ !

Comment: Why the down vote ???? The OP wants to get the limit of $(b_n)$, but he computet the limit of $(\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n})$. The Op asked "what am I missing ?" and I told him that he computed the limit of the wrong sequence ! I think that I gave him a great reply !

Answer (score 0):

From Stirling, we get

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \bigg(\frac{n}{e} \bigg)^n$$ hence $$\frac{n!}{n^{1000}} \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \frac{n^{n-1000}}{e^n}$$

Stirling is always a good trick for handling large factorials.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $n$ is even.

$\log n! -1000 \log n \gt $

$(n/2)\log (n/2) -1000 \log n=$

$(n/2)\log (n/2) -1000 \log (n/2) +1000\log 2=$

$((n/2)-1000)\log (n/2) +$

$1000\log 2>$

$((n/2)-1000)\log (n/2).$

Take the limit  $(n/2) \rightarrow \infty$ of

$\exp ((n/2)-1000)\log (n/2)).$

Remark for large enough $n$:

$\log n! -1000\log n $ is increasing since

$1+1/2+....+1/n -1000/n >0$.